# Adding Low Bandwidth 3G Internet Access to Embedded Device

Tags: embedded

Do any companies offer devices to allow limited cellular internet connectivity for low bandwidth data transmission.

I'm imagining an embedded device that typically does not have (nor need) internet access but could access the internet via cellular networks to transmit error reports back to home base. Do any companies offer such systems without the need of a full blown data contract?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need high data rates, then I think you want to look into GPRS, not 3G.  Google for "free gprs" and you should be able to come up with something.

I haven't played with one before, but Sparkfun has something that might work.  http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9533

Comment: Definitely don't need high bandwidth. Would be happy with transmitting a text file (say up 100kb). 

What network are devices like this Sparkfun one using? Are you paying for the data?

Comment: Your best bet is to search for free plans.  They seem to exist, but in general you'll need a registered SIM card so you can log into the network.

Comment: You could even just transfer it via many text messages - braindead but effective.